# How to find the rank of when I was awarded a certain tag badge?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

I have seen this in another user's profile, and now I'm interested to find my rank of when I received the `java` tag on [SO](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Is that possible to find this?

> 88th to win design-patterns Bronze tag

Comment: You can figure this out by looking at the badges page, but you can't easily figure out the ordinal from there.

Comment: sorry it is confusing me @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog

Comment: The easiest way to do this is probably to write some JavaScript, possibly in the developer console, to go through all the listings on the badge page, count how many are chronologically before your appearance, then extend that by multiplying remaining pages by users per page and counting the ones on the oldest page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you *just* received the specific tag badge, you can visit the appropriate tag badge page and see where you are relative to the total amount awarded. The list will be ordered in reverse chronological order. For example, the [`java` bronze tag badge on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/276) has been awarded 6,682 times at the time of posting:

[image]

If you're somewhere on that first page, it should be easy enough to identify your rank.

If, however, you want to know your rank in general, you'll have to resort to a query on [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com). [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/971622/rank-of-users-who-earned-the-bronze-java-tag-badge) ranks the users from those who achieved the bronze `java` tag badge first (rank 1) to last. Based on [the time you earned the bronze `java` tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/276/java?userid=9959152), it was straight forward to identify your rank:

[image]

You were 6,465th to earn this badge.

Note that, at the time of writing, only 6,668 badges have been logged on SEDE; it's short about 20 badges from the live site. SEDE may be a week behind as it's only [updated once a week](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq).